# Sublime CodeIntel Catalog for PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, catalog, sublimecodeintel

I work with that tutorial to build a PyQt4 Catalog for my Sublime-Package:
[LINK](http://community.activestate.com/faq/generate-python-api-catalog)
But it just generate this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<codeintel description="Python PyQt4" name="PyQt4" version="2.0">
  <file lang="Python" mtime="1390053615" path="__init__.py">
    <scope doc="# Copyright (c) 2013 Riverbank Computing Limited &lt;info@riverbankcomputing.com&gt;&#10;# # This file is part of PyQt. # # This file may be used under the terms of the GNU General Public # License versions 2.0 or 3.0 as published by the Free Software # Foundation and appearing in the files LICENSE.GPL2 and LICENSE.GPL3 # included in the packaging of this file.  Alternatively you may (at # your option) use any later version of the GNU General Public # License if such license has been publicly approved by Riverbank # Computing Limited (or its successors, if any) and the KDE Free Qt" ilk="blob" lang="Python" name="PyQt4" />
  </file>
</codeintel>
```

Do you know why or do you know a Catalog i can download?